# A Matlabber's Nth attempt at spinning up on R: Vector vs. single-column/row matrix

Tags: r

Unlike Matlab, in which everything is a multidimensional array, R distinguishes between a vector and a Nx1 matrix (or a 1xN matrix).  Is there a way to determine whether a variable or object is a vector or a matrix?  the class() function seems to return the type of the elements within a vector/matrix, but doesn't say whether the argument is a vector or single column/row matrix.

As a related question, does R distinguish between a scalar versus an array or vector?  In Matlab, a scalar is a matrix (of dimensions 1x1, or 1x1x1x...x1 in a multidimensional sense).

Comment: `is.vector` and `is.matrix`. `is.vector(c(1,2))` versus `is.vector(matrix(c(1,2),nrow=1))`

Comment: Thanks. And is.vector(1) yields TRUE while is.matrix(1) yields false.  Did you want to post that as the answer, CPak?

Comment: Almost everything in R is a vector. A matrix is just a vector with a dimension attribute. There are no scalars in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is.vector` and `is.matrix` will distinguish them, respectively.

```
is.vector(c(1,2))
# TRUE

is.vector(matrix(c(1,2),nrow=1))
# FALSE
```

Comment: I find it odd that using indexing to extract a single-column/row from a matrix yields a vector rather than a matrix: `is.vector(myMatrix[,1])` yields `TRUE`;  `is.matrix(myMatrix[,1])` yields `FALSE`;  `is.vector(myMatrix[1:2,1:2])` yields `FALSE`; `is.matrix(myMatrix[1:2,1:2])` yields `TRUE.

Comment: Since you're coming from Matlab, it'll take you a while to get used to I imagine

Comment: Yes...the type of macro object returned by matrix indexing depends on the indexing.  Even if the element types are the same throughout.

Comment: @user36800 Take a moment to read [some documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html).

Comment: Thanks...those pages look like reference pages, which can be helpful if one has the necessary conceptual context.  I'm limited in what I can extract from them until after I've exposed myself to more tutorial orientated content (which I am doing now).